# Verb *leave* and an unusual copular construction?

Tags: copular-verbs

A recent question on verb agreement left me one unresolved issue — can we add the verb *leave* to the list of verbs with copular uses?

> The heat left me parched.
> The shutdown left me out of a job.
> The scandal left me boss.

The verb has a weak semantic value that contributes aspectual information, but little else. The same is true of *turns out*, *remains*, and *stays*. These all appear on copular verb lists.

*Leave* does not work in the common copular construction where a subject is matched to a complement that is usually a noun or adjective, but may sometimes be a number of other things.

Rather, it works as an object-focused copula (a label I found in only one document on the web, so I'm hoping for a more established term).

Examples of object-focused copulas include

> Naming verbs — They made her the manager
> Positioning verbs — She put it down
>
> [image: ELT]
> https://www.eltconcourse.com/training/inservice/verbs/copular_verbs_complements.html

The first involves a noun phrase and the second an adverbial. What happened to object-focused adjective complements? Adjective complements are extremely common subject compliments.

Is "leave" an object-focused copula above? Is *parched* an adjective complement to the object?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote was given; perhaps a better attribution was desired. // Note that 'The heat left me parched' is causative and certainly uses an object-orientated resultative, while 'They decided to leave' (cf 'found') 'the baby crying gently in his cot' is hopefully non-causative, using an object-orientated depictive. 'Pseudo-copula' may not be a widely accepted term.

Comment: Agreeing with Edwin Ashworth: To leave is ambitransitive - even if there is no object, an object can be implied.

Comment: All your examples include an object: leave me X. And: turns out, remains, and stays cannot take me like that.

Comment: @Lambie Exactly. Look at the bottom of the chart. I said the same in my question. Object focused copulas connect the object to a compliment. Leave does this, the others do not. But the semantic content is quite similar.

Comment: You are driving me crazy by leaving out all the dashes in object-focused copulas. :) I'm a dashes gal. [ha ha]

Comment: 'This scolding left her speechless' and 'This scolding rendered her speechless' where 'render' is unquestionably causative have a very large degree of overlap. The 'depart' sense of 'leave' doubtless skews this to some small degree, but the resultative construction is clear in both.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And that distinction very much to the point. I am interested in cases where the verb has precious little semantic value, providing some aspectual color, but nothing more.  *His unexpected departure left her flummoxed.* Not the best example, but some responses are basically reflexes (or reactions) and are merely triggered by some situation. They look like they fit the pattern and meet the basic requirements of a copula.

Comment: I apologize for the slow responses and crap editing, I'm have terrible internet problems at the moment. It took 20 minutes for the last comment to post. I jab "post" every chance I can.

Comment: Frankly, I see no difference between: left her flummoxed and flummoxed her. As an editor, I would remove the verb leave there.

Comment: @Lambie The difference is that using flummoxed as a verb (which I wasn't aware of) makes it causative or resultative, whereas using leave and having flummoxed as an adjective changes it to a depictive case. Becoming flummoxed is something that has internal causes. It is only triggered by the departure, and I avoid causal structures in those cases. English seems to be quite concerned about making the distinction.

Comment: @Lambie "The switch turns the light red". I consider this depictive, not resultative, because if I replace the light with a different one, I don't know what the result will be anymore. The switch triggers a response, but the result depends on the specific item that is triggered. Emotional responses work the same way. Resultatives don't depend on the instance of the recipient. If an accident left them paralyzed, it is reasonable to assume that it would have left anybody paralyzed. I score that resultative.

Comment: @PhilSweet You didn't know flummox could be verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468)'s take on this is that *leave* is a ***complex-transitive verb with depictive predicative complement.***

### Discussion

**1. Predicative complements (PCs) and complex-transitive and complex-intransitive constructions**

To begin with, here is how CGEL introduces the complex-intransitive and the complex transitive construction (in the same place where it introduces predicative complements):

> [2]         COMPLEX-INTRANSITIVE                      COMPLEX-TRANSITIVE
>          a.  *This    seems    a
> good
> idea/fair.*          b.  *I    consider    this    a
> good idea / fair.*
>                  S           P                     PC                            S          P             O<sup>d</sup>                  PC
>
> We use the term **complex-intransitive** for a clause containing a
> predicative complement but no object, and **complex-transitive** for
> one containing both types of complement.
>
> The major syntactic difference between a predicative complement and an
> object is that the former can be realised by an adjective, such as
> *fair* in these examples. Semantically, an object characteristically refers to some participant in the situation but with a different
> semantic role from the subject, whereas a predicative complement
> characteristically denotes a property that is ascribed to the referent
> of the subject (in a complex-intransitive)or object (in a
> complex-transitive).

**2. Copula vs. complex-intransitive construction**

CGEL uses the term *copula* only for certain uses of the verb ***be.*** In a note on p. 218, CGEL says that

> The term 'copular' is widely used for [5i] (*Ed seemed quite
> competent*, [complex-intransitive: S-P-PC<sup>S</sup>]) and the like
> as well as [8] (*Ed was quite competent*); we prefer to restrict it to
> the latter, using 'complex-intransitive' for the more general
> construction, partly to bring out the parallel between [5i] (*Ed
> seemed quite competent*) and [5ii] (*She considered Ed quite
> competent* [complex-transitive: S-P-O-PC<sup>O</sup>]), partly because
> complex-intransitive verbs other than *be* are not mere syntactic
> copulas but do express semantic predication.

In short, verbs other than ***be*** that other sources call copular CGEL prefers to label **complex-intransitive** verbs. And what your source calls 'object-focused copulas', CGEL would call 'complex-transitive'.

**3. The classification of the verb *leave* and similar complex-transitive verbs**

Terminology aside, CGEL provides a classification of verbs taking predicative complements (pp. 263–266). The verb *leave* appears in 'Class 3' (pp. 264–265):

> ■ **Class 3 verbs: complex-transitives with depictive PCs**
>
> [39]  *She **believed** it prudent/an advantage to be out of
> town.      We **proved** it genuine/a
> fake.       They **kept** their
> marriage secret/a secret.*
>
> There are considerably more verbs in this class, and we therefore list
> separately those with the 'inf ' annotation indicating the possibility
> of an infinitival complement instead of the PC: compare the *believe*
> and *prove* examples in [39] with *She believed it to be prudent to
> stay out of town* and *We proved it to be genuine.*
>
> [The annotation 'adj' indicates that the PC is restricted, or
> virtually restricted, to AdjPs to the exclusion of NPs.]
>
> [40]  i  *believe*
> inf    *certify*
> inf       *consider*
> inf    *declare*
> inf          *deem*
> inf
>              *feel*
> inf           *find*
> inf            *hold*<sub>1</sub>
> adj inf    *judge*
> inf            *like*
> inf
>              *prefer*
> inf     *presume*
> inf    *profess*
> inf      *pronounce*
> inf    *prove* inf
>              *reckon*
> inf    *report*
> inf        *rule*
> inf            *think*
> inf              *want*
> inf
>
> ii  *account*        *brand*             *call*                    *designate*<sub>1</sub>          *esteem*
>               *have*
> adj       *hold*<sub>2</sub>              *imagine*           *keep*                     *label*
>               *leave*            *rate*                 *term*                 *wish*
> adj
>
> *Hold*<sub>1</sub> means roughly "consider", as in *I hold you responsible for her safety,* while *hold*<sub>2</sub> is close to
> "keep", as in *She held the door open for us; They held us hostage*
> (in both cases the range of PCs is quite limited). Some verbs in [ii]
> do enter into the infinitival complement construction but without the
> semantic equivalence that obtains in [i]. For example, *He wished
> himself different from the sort of person he thought he was* is closer
> to *He wished that he were different* than to *He wished himself to be
> different* (which indicates wanting to change). *He imagined himself
> unmarried* does have an interpretation equivalent to *He imagined
> himself to be unmarried* (i.e. "He thought he was unmarried" - cf. *He
> imagined himself indispensable*) but it also has another
> interpretation, probably more salient,  in which he knew he wasn't
> unmarried but imagined what it would be like if he were.
>
> A few verbs not included above, such as *acknowledge, confess,
> suppose,* appear in the complex-transitive construction, but normally
> only with a reflexive object: *He confessed himself puzzled by her
> response,* but not <sup>*</sup>*He confessed the decision
> indefensible.*

For completeness, here is an abbreviate description of all five classes of verbs taking PCs:

**Class 1 verbs: complex-intransitives with depictive PCs** (this class includes ***be***):

*Kim **felt** lonely/an intruder.    Her son **remained** ill/a danger.    That **seems** plausible/a good idea.    Pat **proved** reliable/a great asset.*

**Class 2 verbs: complex-intransitives with resultative PCs**

*He **became** ill/our main ally.    The work **got** too difficult for them.*

**Class 3 verbs: complex-transitives with depictive PCs**

*She **believed** it prudent/an advantage to be out of town.      We **proved** it genuine/a fake.       They **kept** their marriage secret/a secret.*

**Class 4 verbs: complex-transitives with obligatory resultative PCs**

*They **appointed** her ambassador to Canada.    You **drive** me mad.    They **made** him anxious/ treasurer.    They **created** her a life peer.*

**Class 5 verbs: complex-transitives with optional resultatives**

*We **hammered** it flat.    Kim **knocked** him senseless.    You should **paint** the house green.    She **rubbed** herself dry.    He **pushed** the door open.    I'll **wipe** it clean.*

### Addendum

As Edwin Ashworth pointed out in the comments, it seems that *leave* really can be used in two senses, one depictive (which therefore belongs to Class 3), and one resultative, which arguably belongs to Class 4:

[A]  i  *They **left***<sub>1</sub> *him sleeping/asleep on the couch.*       [depictive]
       ii  *The crisis **left***<sub>2</sub> *him pennyless/a pauper.*              [resultative]

The authors of CGEL anticipated that some of these distinctions might have been left out of their classification (pp. 265–266):

> The primarily semantic distinction between depictive and resultative
> PCs is not always easy to draw. We have distinguished two senses of
> *designate* with one taking a depictive ("officially classify", as in *They have designated*<sub>1</sub> *it a disaster area*), and the other a resultative ("choose, appoint", as in *They have designated*<sub>2</sub> *Kim the
> next Attorney-General*), and it may be that some others should
> likewise be dually classified. Compare, for example, *We had half the
> children sick* (depictive) vs *We had the meal ready in half an hour*
> (resultative).

Comment: Note that 'they left him sleeping / asleep on the couch' is a depictive usage, but 'the plague left many dead' is resultative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good point! I've added an Addendum to the answer that reflects this. Someone should send an email to Huddleston and Pullum to have this included in the CGEL [erratum](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/cgelerrata.html).

Comment: This answer contains the word "predictive" in several places, as well as "predicative" - should they all be "predicative"?

Comment: @psmears Ooops, good catch! Corrected.

Comment: "He confessed himself puzzled by her response", and "He confessed the decision indefensible". I would use: He confessed he was puzzled by her response. and the second one for me is not grammatical. It would have to be: He confessed his decision was indefensible.

Comment: Alex B. on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/what-is-the-difference-between-a-copula-and-a-transitive-verb/1677#1677) looks at different terminology, but _seem_ is normally classed as a raising-to-subject verb rather than a a pseudo-copula.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth CGEL does spend quite a bit of time—in several other sections—on the issue of raising vs control, with *seem* being a prime example of a raising verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth While the terminology here is definitely not standardized, let me just mention that McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* also seems to reserve the term 'copula' just for the verb ***be,*** and doesn't introduce semi- or pseudo-copulas.

Comment: Oh, I'm not recommending that classification. I was brought up on 'link verbs' ('He grew tired') and 'link-like verbs' (having semantic content too: 'The rose blushed pink').